# difference between assigning a var as a class and creating one nomally

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im new to JS and react, and just curious about a few (probably simple) things are. Im trying to make reusable radio buttons using exports and imports in reactJS.

Im trying to understand the difference between these two things is

```
var RadioInput = React.createClass({
render: function() {
 .....
 };
});
```

and

```
export class RadioInput extends Component {
 render(){
 ....
};
}
```

is.

Thanks! Sorry if this is a ridiculous question

Comment: In javascript a `class` is just syntactic sugar for functions

Comment: The basic difference is that in your first example you are not exporting anything.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding javascript, a `class` is just a "special type of function", syntactic sugar for the prototype inheritance using constructors, so the following statements serve the same purpose:

```
// Constructor Function
function Dog() {
  this.bark = "woof"
}


// Class Syntax
class Dog {
  constructor(){
    this.bark = "woof";
  }
}
```

Hence, you can assign a class to a variable the same way you assign a function:

```
const Dog = function() {
  this.bark = "woof";
}

const Dog = class {
  constructor() {
    this.bark = "woof";
  }
}
```